# The Minesweeper Puzzle That Might Stump People

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, minesweeper

I thought this might be a different kind of puzzle. This is a game of Minesweeper that I played earlier today.

All standard rules apply. For those who don't know, the number inside of each cell represents how many mines are in the 8 cells surrounding it. There are 35 mines in the 15x15 grid. All 0's are shown, although that is not necessarily true about the other numbers.

[image: Minesweeper Grid]

This is my own puzzle that I created. I coded the Minesweeper game. This is a screenshot from my work computer. I thought it'd be an interesting puzzle where you couldn't ask for extra clues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Simple reasoning already gets us this far: [image]

> Then reasoning of the form "$n$ mines in $n+1$ squares, but one placement violates another clue, so mines must be here" already gives us the solution: [image]